# How many elements are in the set $S^S$, where $S=\{a,b\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If set $S =\{a,b\}$, then how many elements will be in set $S^S$?

Here $S^S$ is {Set S is Exponent of S}.

Do we need to do cross product like $S*S$ when it says $(S^S)$.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you explicitly state what $S^S$ means? I've never ever seen a set as an exponent to a set.

Comment: Is $S^S$ the set of all functions $S\to S$?

Answer (score 4):

If $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then $Y^X$ is the set of all functions $X\to Y$.

It is a general fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are finite, then $\left\lvert Y^X\right\rvert=\left\lvert Y\right\rvert^{\left\lvert X\right\rvert}$.

In our case $S^S$ is the set of functions $S\to S$ and we have 
$$
\left\lvert S^S\right\rvert=\left\lvert S\right\rvert^{\left\lvert S\right\rvert}=2^2=4
$$
These four maps are
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccc}
a&\mapsto& a&&  a&\mapsto&a&& a&\mapsto&b&& a&\mapsto&b\\
b&\mapsto& a&&  b&\mapsto&b&& b&\mapsto&a&& b&\mapsto&b
\end{array}

Comment: if I want to list all elements of S^S,then shall we do a cross product?

Comment: Total functions  from {a,b} --> {a,b}={{a,a},{a,b},{b,a},{b,b}} .Please advise if I am wrong